# What's the easiest way for me to make boost::statechart::state_machine thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, state-machine

I'm working with a `boost::statechart::state_machine` and I experienced a crash in the machine.  Upon investigation of the core I realized that it happened because multiple threads processed an event around the same time, one of which called terminate and the other of which crashed because it tried to use a terminated object.

I therefore need to know what my options are for making my state machine thread-safe.  In looking at the boost's `statechard` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html%20documentation), it explicitly says that `statechart::state_machine` is not thread-safe and indicates that thread-safety can be accomplished by `aynchronous_state_machine`.  But `asynchronous_state_machine` looks like it solves more problems than just thread safety and converting from `state_machine` to `asynchronous_state_machine` looks non-trivial.  Can I achieve a thread-safe implementation by simply locking around my calls to process_event?

Comment: You must provide thread-safety by using locks around all shared objects that are not explicitly thread-save or immutable. That is not trivial and if you have a legacy code base full of race conditions you have a problem. There are [ways to make this easier](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html), but it depends on the platform you are using. So the answer is *"Yes, but it is hard"*.

Comment: @nwp: I'm essentially doing this.  I inherited from statechart::state_machine and masked all the public functions by implementing our own that first locks then calls the base function.  state_machine's functions aren't virtual, so they aren't technically overriding them, but they are masking them and our use isn't polymorphic. As far as I know this should get us what we need.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to mutex semaphores or locks, you might consider a monitor.

- The state machine can possibly be just as you have it now.

There are several kinds I know of, and I have (not so recently) used a Hoare Monitor for a state machine of my own design (not boost).

From wiki-pedia: "In concurrent programming, a monitor is a synchronization construct that allows threads to have both mutual exclusion and the ability to wait (block) for a certain condition to become true. "

My implementation of a Hoare Monitor transformed any event (input to my state machine) into an IPC message to the monitor thread.  Only the monitor thread modifies the state machine.  This machine (and all its states) are private data to the class containing the monitor thread and its methods.

Some updates must be synchronous, that is, a requesting thread suspends until it receives an IPC response. Some updates can be asynchronous, so the requesting thread need not wait.  While processing one thread request, the monitor ignores the other thread requests, their requests simply queue until the monitor can get to them.

Since only 1 thread is allowed to directly modify the (private data attribute) state machine, no other mutex schemes are needed.

That effort was for a telecommunications device, and the events were mostly from human action, there for not time critical.

---

The state machine can possibly be just as you have it now.  You only need to implement the monitor thread, decide on an IPC (or maybe inter-thread-comm) and ensure that only the one thread will have access to the state machine.